# android - kotlin - mvvm - posting data to webservice

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle, android-livedata, android-mvvm

I want to post some data to webservice and get the result . this is my code :

```
fab.setOnClickListener {
 viewModel.newBimeGozar(name)
                    .observe(this@BimeGozarAct, Observer {
                        dialogbimegozarNew?.hidePg()
                    })
}
```

this is my viewmodel :

```
class BimeNewViewModel:ViewModel() {
private val repository=BimeNewRepository()

fun newBimeGozar(name: String): MutableLiveData<StatModel> {
    return repository.newBimeGozar(name)
}
```

this is my repository :

```
fun newBimeShode(
    name: String
): MutableLiveData<StatModel> {
    scope.launch {
        val request = api.newBimeShode(name)
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            try {
                val response = request.await()
                regBimeshodeLiveData.value = response
            } catch (e: HttpException) {
                Log.v("this", e.message);
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
                Log.v("this", e.message);
            }
        }
    }
    return regBimeshodeLiveData;
}
```

it works fine but there is a problem . I think the observer keeps running and if the result's answer is an error and user press fab button again , it creates a new observer and after this , it returns two value , the first value is the first run and the second value is the second run

how can I fix this ? what is the correct way for  submitting forms ?

Comment: I think the best solution is `disable` the button after first time submit.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is because of `LiveData`, you should use `SingleLiveEvent` like as follow

```
// For first article
val _liveData = MutableLiveData<Event<StatModel>>()

// For second article
val _liveData = SingleLiveEvent<StatModel>()
```

If you do not know `SingleLiveEvent`, you can find it [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150) and [here](https://proandroiddev.com/livedata-with-single-events-2395dea972a8).

If your problem is because of your ui element, I think the best solution is to `disable` the submit button after submitting for the first time.

Comment: I think SingleLiveEvent in the associated links iss already MutableLiveData or MediatorLiveData, don't need to wrap it into another MutableLiveData imo.